# How to make a Chartkick Multipleseries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm practically new on ruby on rails and having a hard time on making multipleseries on chartkick.

Based on :
http://chartkick.com/

Making Chartkick multipleseries is easy as :

```
<%= line_chart @goals.map{|goal|
    {:name => goal.name, :data => goal.feats.group_by_week(:created_at).count }
} %>
```

but it seems to me is not working as it should since group_by deprecated in rails 4.

is there a way to produce the same effect like the code above?

thank you

Comment: This may help you:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of chartkick. Can you provide more info on what you're trying to do?